# google drive migration api

Tags: api, migrate

I received the following email and have been IM'ing with google support for an hour. They have no idea how to direct me to migrate the drive. Can someone please advise as to what to do.  See email below:

Google
IMPORTANT: Steps to migrate from discontinued Documents List API
Hello administrators,

We recently posted a reminder that Documents List API will be discontinued on April 20, 2015. This change means that service calls for this API will no longer be supported, and any Google Apps features that are implemented using this API will no longer function.

Our records indicate that you may have an application that uses Documents List API, and we  recommend that you migrate to Drive API, which has comparable functionality, as soon as possible.

Here's what you need to do:

Determine if you have an application that makes requests to these types of URLs:
*lists multiple links here that I can't post in the thread*

Migrate the applications to Drive API.

If you have questions about migration, please contact Google Apps for Work Support.

Sincerely,
The Google Apps for Work Team

Comment: You need to follow the instructions and migrate your code to use the Drive API. What that entails for you is anybody's guess because you haven't even hinted at what use you might be making of the Documents List API.

Comment: What if there are no instructions?

Comment: The instructions I refer to are contained in the email you received from Google under the heading _'Here's what you need to do'_. If you don't understand the process of migrating from one API to another I suggest you hire someone.

Comment: so it says the following:

Comment: Here's what you need to do:

Determine if you have an application that makes requests to these types of URLs:

https://docs.google.com/feeds/

https://docs.googleusercontent.com/

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/

Migrate the applications to Drive API.

Comment: when i click on all those links it says error message or invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same challenge. I am not a programmer but I found this video very useful - https://youtu.be/fD2uPlcFOZM.

In short it is a walk through of the solution, it seems not everyone will need to do this update as it may have been carried out by a third party. Watch the video to see what I mean.

Comment: Please state in short the solution, not only the link to it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer